# ...and the difference being the "a" or the "e" — what does "being" mean?

Tags: gerunds

Here is a sentence from [a video on EngVid](http://www.engvid.com/confusing-words-affect-effect-compliment-complement-and-more/) (0:32):

> Now, we're going to start with "affect" and "effect", and the difference **being** the "a" or the "e".

What does *being* mean here?

I know that this word can be used to show a cause, but I don't see any causal relationship in this sentence.

My second guess is that the teacher uses the whole phase *the difference being the "a" or the "e"* as a noun (together with *affect and effect*) or something of the kind, and *being* is just a regular gerund here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sentence

> Now, we're going to start with "affect" and "effect", and the difference being the "a" or the "e".

the part that starts with 'and' *is supposed to be* a *participle clause*, but the '*and*' interferes with that.  Properly constructed, the sentence would be

> Now, we're going to start with "affect" and "effect", the difference being the "a" or the "e".

The use of the conjunction 'and' makes it a compound sentence with two *independent* clauses.  For the second clause to be independent it needs a predicate ('*difference*' is the subject).  The gerund/participle "*being*" cannot be the predicate, it's not a verb.  Replace it with "is", and you get a correct sentence:

> Now, we're going to start with "affect" and "effect", *and* the *difference* *is* the "a" or the "e".

Since it's a video, you need to give the speaker a bit of slack.  They may have cue cards to help them, but it's not uncommon to mistakenly put an 'and' or a 'but' where it doesn't belong even while reading.